# Pandas hierarchy/complex conditions to drop duplicates

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a large dataset of locations - there is a sample below.

I need to find and drop duplicates. There are some obvious duplicates, which have the same address, name and borough, but also some almost equal rows, which identify 2 different locations (such as the last 2 rows of the sample below).
To complicate things, most location have a missing name, so I only have the address and the borough, and the address doesn't always have a number.

The borough also is inconsistent, but I found a way to simplify it (see below).

```py
addresses = ['regents street', '21 regent street',
             'bishopgate 3', '3 bishopgate', 'bishop gate', 'regent',
             'hill park', 'hill park road', '10 hill park road',
             '12 hill park', 'south street', 'south street', 'east street', '2 east street', 'cup street', 'bond street',
            '80 cobbler road', '88 cobbler road']

name = ['a','a','b','b','b','c','d','e','e','d', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 'g', 'h']
boroughs = ['royal borough of greenwhich', 'borough of greenwhich', 
            'royal borough of chelsea', 'chelsea', 'borough of chelsea',
            'greenwhich', 'haringey', 'haringey', 'borough of haringey', 'haringey',
           'southwark', 'southwark', 'hammersmith', 'borough of hammersmith', 
            'hackney', 'hackney', 'lambeth', 'lambeth']


df = pd.DataFrame({'address':addresses, 'name':name, 'borough':boroughs})
# to simplify the borough columns i do this
df['borough'] = df['borough'].str.replace('royal|royal borough of|borough of', '', regex=True)
```

I though I could clean up the address too with:
`df['address'] = df['address'].str.replace('\d+', '', regex=True)`
but then I lose information about different locations on the same street.

Any ideas on how I could do it? (I tried things such as groupby([...]).max() but without success).

P.S. If one address is present only once in different format (e.g. 'east street' and '2 east street') I'm going to assume that they refer to the same location and therefore only one record should be kept.

Comment: Which address would be duplicates? "Bishopgate 3" and "3 bishopgate" are obvious, but is "hill park" and "hill park road" a duplicate?

Comment: There is no builtin pandas method to do that. You'll have to write a small program with a set of rules. Please focus your question to a specific issue, at the moment it rather looks like you're requesting someone to write a full solution for you.

Comment: In that case, 'hill park' is different from 'hill park road'. Also mozway, I guess I am trying to figure out conceptually a way on how to do it, without looping over each row, fuzzymatching and double checking everything, as it would take an extremely long time to run. I asked here in case there was a quick method that I might have been missing.

Comment: No, there is no "quick method", you'll have to set up all wanted comparisons.

Comment: Do you have post codes? Maybe you can enhance the data by using a post code dataset to help fill in the blanks?